# How do I see last commit that a line existed before it was deleted in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

For example, if in the first commit I've introduced a line 'example-line' to file 'f.txt', and in the third commit I've deleted that line from 'f.txt', and now I'm in the fifth commit. How can I tell in Visual Studio code (or any other simple way) that 'example-line' was deleted in the third commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find the deletion commit with

```
git log -1 -S "example-line"
```

(see `-S` doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt))